# What is best way to fill out a related table after processing the parent field , DRF

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a class like bellow:

```
class News(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

it has a text field.Now I am supposed to list the entities that are in this text, so I defined a related table as bellow:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(
        News,
        related_name='entities4thisnews',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        entity = models.TextField(verbose_name="Entity", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="")
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As an example I have this text in first table

**news1ID, " France is in Europe".**

when user posts it second table should be automatically filled with

**entityID1,news1ID, France**

**entityID2,news1ID, Europe**

when the user posts a news, my question is that where is the best place to process the text(finding entity in this case), and post the processed results accordingly to the next table?

An issue right of the bat is that, newsID1 is not determined before any post for the news.

here are also my views.

```
class NewsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    name = 'news-list'
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        pass

class EntityList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer
    name = 'entity-list'
```

Thanks for your help!